# How to add authorization before each postman request?

Tags: api, request, postman

So, I've got simple get request, but I need to log in before execute it, and I cannot do this through token in authorization section cause token expires in 5 mins, so what should I do to add authorization procedure(post request with JSON data for example) before this get request?

Comment: basic auth option isn't works either just to notice

Comment: can you generate this token by calling some API?

Comment: User gets a token after authorization, and a new token after each 4.5 mins by automatically sending get_new_token request, but this request cannot be executed without having a token too

Comment: How does a user get this token after authorization? How is this first call authenticated? Basic Auth maybe? And this token is obtained from some other API/endpoint? Explain your authentication flow a little more in detail and maybe we can help.